# Search all fathers with conditions in Prolog

Tags: list, search, prolog

I have a family tree program in Prolog that contain next facts:

```
male(alex). 
male(david).
male(peter).
etc
...
female(sofia).
etc
....
parent(alex, peter).
parent(sofia, peter).  
etc
....
```

and some rules such as:

```
father(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), male(X).
mother(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), female(X).
etc
....
```

I need to find all fathers who has two or more children.
I think that I need to go through all fathers im my program, put their children to list and count it's length, then if >=2 I add this father to another list or just print him and go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in the general case when you want to find all fathers with at least `N` children your approach would be required, a much simpler approach is available when you are dealing with only two children: find a child twice, and see if the two children are different.

In Prolog this rule would look like this:

```
father_of_two(X) :-
    father(X, A),
    father(X, B),
    A \= B.
```

All you need to do now is collecting all people who match `father_of_two` predicate into a list.

Comment: In this case I'd need to know name of X and I can check only one person per launch. In my case I need to write all the fathers with two or more children w/o knowledge of their names. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: @slxvxBatih This is not a complete solution, it's a rule from which you can build a complete solution by doing what I mentioned in the last sentence (reload the page if you don't see the edit).

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't reload the page. Thanks!